# React Native Remove Item and button

Tags: reactjs, react-native

### I want when I click button inside access file remove the same item in months array inside Home file.
How can I solve this?

App.js
this file conncet screen.

```
import {StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import Home from './src/components/Home';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import Access from './src/components/access';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const App = () => {
  return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
          <Stack.Screen name="access" component={Access} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default App;
```

`ButtonCicle.js`
this file make circle.

```
import { View, Text,TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import styles from './Styles/ButtonCircleStyles';

export default function ButtonCicle({BtnName, onPress}) {
    return (
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonContainer} onPress={onPress}>
            <Text style={styles.button}>{BtnName}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
}
```

`ButtonCircleStyles.js`

```
this file make style
import {StyleSheet, Dimensions} from 'react-native';
const height = Dimensions.get('window').height;
const width = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    buttonContainer:
    {
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        borderRadius: 50,
        width: width / 5,
        height: width / 5,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        marginStart: '4%',
        marginBottom: '4%',
    },
    button:
    {
        fontSize: 25,
        textAlign: 'center',
    },
});

export default styles;
```

`Home.js`
this file make array and onPress to another screen

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native';
import ButtonCicle from './ButtonCircle';

const Home = ({navigation}) => {
  const months = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];

  const listbutton = months.map((i, key) => (
    <ButtonCicle
      BtnName={i}
      key={key}
      onPress={() =>  navigation.navigate('access') || alert(i)}
      />
  ));
  return (
    <>
      <View style={styles.container}>{listbutton}</View>
    </>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
    marginTop: '10%',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    height: 300,
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
});

export default Home;
```

`access.js`

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native'

export default function access({navigation}) {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>Home</Text>
            <Button title='Click' onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')} />
        </View>
    )
}
```

I want when I click button inside access file remove the same item in months array inside Home file.
How can I solve this?
How create it ?

Comment: Younis Can you please explain properly what are you trying to achieve? This is not clear from the question. Do you want to remove the element from the month array which was clicked?

Comment: Yes, I want to remove element from the month array inside access file.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with a callback. Define a function inside Home.js that remove the element from the array. Then you could pass this callback as a route param

```
navigation.navigate('access', {deleteItem: //your callback})
```

And in the access.js file you get this callback

```
const deleteItem = navigation.getParam('deleteItem');
```

And call it before navigate back to home

```
const onPress = () => {
  deleteItem();
  navigation.navigate('Home');
}

 <Button title='Click' onPress={onPress} />
```

Comment: Not working when I passed callback function.
display message :
non-serializable values were found in the navigation state, which can break usage such as persisting and restoring state. this might happen if you passed non-serializable values such as function, class instances etc. in params. if you need to use components with callbacks in your options, you can use 'navigation.setoptions' instead

Comment: home file:
  const deleteItem = (i) => months.slice(i, 1);
  const listbutton = months.map((i, key) => (
    <ButtonCicle
      BtnName={i}
      key={key}
      onPress={() =>  navigation.navigate('access',{
        deleteItem:() => deleteItem() ,
        }) }
      />
  ));
-----------------
access file :
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, Button} from 'react-native';

export default function access({navigation,route}) {
  const {deleteItem} = route.params;

    const onPress = () => {
        deleteItem();
        navigation.navigate('Home');
      };